# Make a absolute:position div slide to left and fadeout - Bootstrap on WordPress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

In my WordPress based on Bootstrap v.4.3 framework, I have an image based carousal and a solid-color layer div on top of it.
I want the solid-color layer to fade-out and reveal the beneath carousal image for each `carousel-item`, example in this theme (https://themes.muffingroup.com/be/architect5/?utm_source=demos).

Below the HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid home-slide no-gutters" id="home-slide">
    <!-- IMAGES ROW -->
    <div class="row slide-images-row">
        <div id="carousel-home" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="/img/one.png" class="img-responsive d-block"/>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="/img/two.png" class="img-responsive d-block"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- SOLID LAYER ROW -->
    <div class="row slide-layer-row">
        <div class="slide-layer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below the CSS for positioning the `.slide-layer-row` row div, which is solid-color layer on top of carousal:

```
.home-slide {
    position: relative;
}
.slide-layer-row {
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

I have aligned the `.slide-layer` to animate the fadeout using jQuery on the carousal events with below code:

```
$('#carousel-home').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
    $(".slide-layer").css('background-color', '#ccc');
    $(".slide-layer").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
});
$('#carousel-home').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    $(".slide-layer").css('background-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)');
});
```

The slide-to-left and fadeOut is not happening.
Here is the JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/kingBethal/s1g56bf0/8/).
Help me out.

Comment: Can you create a working fiddle or codepen please

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kingBethal/s1g56bf0/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case i am using bootstrap carousels `active` class and `pseudo` element to to give the grey `background`

```css
.slide-images-row {
  z-index: 0;
}

.home-slide {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.slide-layer-row {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  margin: 0;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide-layer-out,
.slide-layer-in {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.slide-layer-out {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.slide-layer-in {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.carousel {
  width:100%;
}

.carousel-item {
}

.carousel-item:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: grey;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-item.active:before {
  animation: mymove 2s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid home-slide no-gutters" id="home-slide">
  <!-- IMAGES ROW -->
  <div class="row slide-images-row">
    <div id="carousel-home" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" class="img-responsive d-block" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png" class="img-responsive d-block" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

What I did was place two divs inside `slide-layer-row` (one for each background color) and move the whole thing over to reveal the next slide. Then reset its position before the next slide. This way, you don't need to watch for the `slid-bs-carousel` event.

https://jsfiddle.net/rgy64uwm/

And if you want that soft quick fade in of the solid block, you can do that with a handful of nested callbacks.

https://jsfiddle.net/8eqkua9s/

---

**Edit:** Added snippet. In this version, the box sizes are dynamically set to match the first image.

```js
var imageWidth = $('.carousel-item.active img').width();
$('.slide-layer-row').css('width', (imageWidth * 3 + 'px'));
$('.slide-layer-out').css('width', imageWidth + 'px');
$('.slide-layer-in').css('width', imageWidth * 2 + 'px');

$('#carousel-home').on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
  $('.slide-layer-out').animate({
    'opacity': '1'
  }, 300, function() {
    $('.slide-layer-row').animate({
      'left': -imageWidth + 'px',
    }, 1000, function() {
      $('.slide-layer-out').animate({
        'opacity': '0.3'
      }, 100, function() {
        $(".slide-layer-row").css({
          'left': '0',
        })
      })
    });
  })
});
```

```css
.slide-images-row {
  z-index: 0;
}

.home-slide {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.slide-layer-row {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 !important;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide-layer-out,
.slide-layer-in {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 1);
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid home-slide no-gutters" id="home-slide">
  <!-- IMAGES ROW -->
  <div class="row slide-images-row">
    <div id="carousel-home" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" class="img-responsive d-block" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png" class="img-responsive d-block" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- SOLID LAYER ROW -->
  <div class="row slide-layer-row">
    <div class="slide-layer-out"></div>
    <div class="slide-layer-in"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is so great.
However, I am going with @Vitorino fernandes considering pure CSS only.

Comment: @theKing Understandable, although his effect is somewhat different from your example in that the grey box dissolves as it slides. But you can easily adjust that by adding an additional step to the animation: `99% {
    width: 1%;
    opacity: 1;
  }`